# Making conference calls (cellular not VoIP) in C# UWP

Tags: c#, api, uwp, windows-phone, conference

I'm trying to figure out how to make a conference call (adding and merging phone calls of different contacts - cellular not VoIP) using C# in UWP.

I see the sample code "PhoneCall" provded in github:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PhoneCall
on how to dial a number:

```
public async void DialOnCurrentLineAsync(string PhoneNumber, string DisplayName)
{
    if ((currentPhoneLine != null) && (PhoneNumber.Trim().Length > 0))
    {
        currentPhoneLine.Dial(PhoneNumber, DisplayName);
    }
    else
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("No line found to place the call");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

But I don't see any part of the code to add and merge calls.

Answer (score 1):

For now, there's no sucn built-in API for you to make conference call in UWP. It should be a feature request. You could submit your feature request on [WP UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/).